# Joins and Views Design aspect

Tags: mysql, join, view

I've recently started using mysql. The immediate doubt that hit my mind was the utility of joins and views. While joins join the tables and views do the same thing,what is the major difference between both of them. I am aware about the fact that views are temporary.

For instance if i have lot of data split across 2 tables. Then i use joins and views to create the combined table and then start querying both the join and view, what difference will it make because at the end of the day, data in both the join and view will be the same i.e the combination of two tables.

Comment: Views and joins don't do the same thing, you can find a tutorial about views on: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-sql-views.aspx

Comment: i think if you add DESC of these 2 tables it will be helpful

Comment: Thanks @Jonas found it helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `VIEW` is merely a subtype of 'table' and is of little interest to most users. If you replaced all your base tables with `VIEW`s and vice versa then it should not have any affect on SQL code as written.

Given the join `authors NATURAL JOIN books` then both `authors` and `books` are tables; they could be base tables or `VIEW`s. So views are objects that can 'participate in joins'; on the other hand, views can have joins included in their definition.

Answer (score 0):

A view is basically a table that is derived from other tables. They can be used to greatly simplify database access. Views are in essence stored queries - as far as I know there's nothing that you can do with views that you can't accomplish without them, but when used properly, they can greatly simplify stuff.

A join is much more low-level. Their primary (and only) use is to join multiple columns together on some common value.

Both are tools to simplify database access, but they each have their own use. The Wikipedia entries for [View (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) and [Join (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) might clarify stuff.